# JVM Cucumber: Running multiple testcase on a single step definition

Tags: java, selenium, testing, cucumber-jvm

I have a scenario in jvm cucmber as below

```
Given I have launched the <app_name> application page
And I fill out the <first_name> and <last_name> on the page
And I click Submit
And I am shown <message> on the <app_name> page based on <decision>
When I fill in username with value <username>
And I fill in password with value <password>
And I fill in confirmPassword with value <confirmPassword>
Then I should see the enroll button enabled for submission
```

In the above case, I want to submit the application only once as it is pretty much high time consuming. Once I submit only, I can get the enroll page as it is bounded by session token. But after that, I want to run multiple test with different sets of username, password and confirmpassword. Is it possible to have multiple test runs after we cross the particular submit step definition. Like a loop of test running.

Answer (score 0):

Use Examples for running the same feature with multiple test values.

```
Feature: Some test feature

    Background:
    Given I have launched the <app_name> application page
    And I fill out the <first_name> and <last_name> on the page
    And I click Submit
    And I am shown <message> on the <app_name> page based on <decision>


    Scenario Outline:
    When I fill in username with value "<username>"
    And I fill in password with value "<password>"
    And I fill in confirmPassword with value "<confirmPassword>"
    Then I should see the enroll button enabled for submission

    Examples:
    |username|password|confirmPassword|
    |usernam1|password1|password1|
    |usernam2|password2|password2|
    |usernam3|password3|password3|
```

Source: [Software Automata](https://softwareautomata.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/selenium-cucumber-passing-parameters/)